# How do I compile a TensorFlow Lite GPU delegate for Windows

Tags: windows, opengl-es, gpu, bazel, tensorflow-lite

I have a TensorFlow Lite C API library that I am using on Windows and I want it to use a GPU delegate. I do not have any trouble compiling the TensorFlow Lite C API library with bazel on my Windows machine, but I cannot get the GPU delegate to compile.

TensorFlow version: 2.10.0

Windows version: 10.0.19044

Even though TFLite does not support the Windows platform there is a clear indication that it should be possible to compile a GPU delegate for the Windows platform using ANGLE library (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28830#issuecomment-522325199).

It feels like I am close to the solution but I must be missing something fundamental. I am quite new to most of the tools and concepts involved, but I managed to stitch together the following procedure:

1. Installed ANGLE according to https://chromium.googlesource.com/angle/angle/+/main/doc/DevSetup.md (COMMIT=596c2acfa5071eb643eaffe855a5ccb51c345427)
2. Built ANGLE libraries with following args (args.gn):

   ```
   is_component_build = false
   target_cpu = "x64"
   is_debug = false
   angle_assert_always_on = false
   ```
3. Added ANGLE build output directory (containing libEGL.dll, libEGL.dll.lib, libGLESv2.dll, libGLESv2.dll.lib, d3dcompiler_47.dll) to PATH environment variable.
4. Added ANGLE library dependency in bazel:

   1. In WORKSPACE file:

      ```
      new_local_repository(
          name = "angle",
          path = "../../../angle/angle/include",
          build_file_content = """
      package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
      cc_library(
          name = "headers",
          srcs = glob(["**/*.h"])
      )
      """
      )
      ```
   2. Added necessary dependencies (copts = ["-Iexternal/angle"] and "@angle//:headers") to targets in bazel BUILD files (all targets that failed compilation due to missing OpenGL headers):

      Example:

      ```
      cc_library(
          name = "gl_errors",
          srcs = ["gl_errors.cc"],
          hdrs = ["gl_errors.h"],
          copts = ["-Iexternal/angle"],             <--- ADDED THIS
          deps = [
              "@angle//:headers",                   <--- ADDED THIS
              ":portable",
              "//tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/common:status",
              "@com_google_absl//absl/strings",
          ],
      )
      ```
5. Updated .bazel to use '/std:c++latest'

   ```
   ---build:windows --cxxopt=/std:c++17
   ---build:windows --host_cxxopt=/std:c++17
   +++build:windows --cxxopt=/std:c++latest
   +++build:windows --host_cxxopt=/std:c++latest
   ```
6. Build TensorFlow Lite GPU delegate (v2.10.0) //tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so

   ```
   bazel2 build --local_cpu_resources=3 --features=windows_export_all_symbols -s -c opt --copt="-DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS" --copt="-DEGL_NO_X11" //tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so
   ```

I expected to get the two files `libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so.dll` and `libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so.if.lib` but I get errors that I do not know how to mitigate.

```
ERROR: C:/users/magnusg/src/tensorflow_lite/tflite_2.10.0_gpu_delegate_build_bazel/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/kernels/BUILD:129:11: Compiling tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/kernels/converter.cc failed: (Exit 2): cl.exe failed: error executing command
  cd /d C:/users/magnusg/_bazel_magnusg/4du655w4/execroot/org_tensorflow
  SET INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.20348.0\cppwinrt
    SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.20348.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/magnusg/anaconda3/envs/sa/python.exe
    SET PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/magnusg/anaconda3/envs/sa/lib/site-packages
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TEMP=C:\Users\magnusg\AppData\Local\Temp
    SET TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
    SET TMP=C:\Users\magnusg\AppData\Local\Temp
    SET avariable=3
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/kernels/_objs/converter/converter.obj.params
# Configuration: 4692499b740a707abb55d09dbd7c915fbefe7b433a9f783356c086c94c980334
# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'experimental:preprocessor' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9036 : use 'Zc:preprocessor' instead of 'experimental:preprocessor'
cl_version.h: CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION is not defined. Defaulting to 300 (OpenCL 3.0)
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(526): error C2059: syntax error: '__cdecl'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(532): error C2065: 'cl_command_buffer_khr': undeclared identifier
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(532): error C2165: 'left-side modifier': cannot modify pointers to data
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(532): error C2513: 'cl_int *': no variable declared before '='
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(535): error C2065: 'cl_command_buffer_khr': undeclared identifier
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(535): error C2165: 'left-side modifier': cannot modify pointers to data
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(535): error C2513: 'cl_int *': no variable declared before '='
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(538): error C2065: 'cl_command_buffer_khr': undeclared identifier
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(538): error C2165: 'left-side modifier': cannot modify pointers to data
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(538): error C2513: 'cl_int *': no variable declared before '='
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(542): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'cl_command_buffer_khr'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(547): error C2065: 'cl_command_buffer_khr': undeclared identifier
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(548): error C2275: 'cl_command_queue': illegal use of this type as an expression
external/angle\CL/cl.h(32): note: see declaration of 'cl_command_queue'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(549): error C2059: syntax error: 'const'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(559): error C2065: 'cl_command_buffer_khr': undeclared identifier
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(560): error C2065: 'cl_command_buffer_info_khr': undeclared identifier
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(560): error C2275: 'size_t': illegal use of this type as an expression
tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/kernels/converter.cc: note: see declaration of 'size_t'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(561): error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(682): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(682): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'clCreateCommandBufferKHR'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(687): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(687): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'clCommandNDRangeKernelKHR'
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(688): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
.\tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/cl/opencl_wrapper.h(688): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'clGetCommandBufferInfoKHR'
Target //tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu:libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 375.856s, Critical Path: 62.04s
INFO: 686 processes: 15 internal, 671 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I do not know if I am on the right track and simply missing a minor detail or if I am missing the target completely. Any feedback would be helpful.